# Android: onBackPressed not being recognized

Tags: java, android

EDIT: Realized and solved the problem on my own. Thank you.

Please bear with me it's actually my first time using Android Studio and Stackoverflow. What I am trying to make is a music player, there are 2 activities. In the second activity when the user taps the play button, the music plays. If the user backs, the music will stop playing and go back to the first activity. Somehow on back pressed is not working. It's grayed out and it tells me that  the Method is never used.

```
package com.radiantminds.radiantminds;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class player1 extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_player1);
        final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.mozardpianosonata); //create mediaplayer with song
        ImageButton yButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton5);
        yButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onBackPressed(){ //this is not working
                if(mp.isPlaying())
                {
                    mp.stop(); // stop music on backpress
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) { //play music on click
                if (mp.isPlaying()) {
                    mp.pause();
                } else {
                    mp.start();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll need to post some code for us to help

Comment: You do realize that Android Studio is an IDE (not an operating system), right?

Comment: Did you put in an Activity?

Comment: Please see: [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354427/how-do-i-avoid-misusing-tags)

Comment: Sorry, just posted the code.

Comment: @Ivannnnn if my answer helped mark it as a correct answer, the green check! thanks ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to put it on an `Activity`, don't forget to call `@Override`

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
     super.onBackPressed();  //if you want to do something new remove this line
}
```

The problem is that you have to place the `onBackPressedMethod()` outside, as follows :

```
public class player1 extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_player1);
        final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.mozardpianosonata); //create mediaplayer with song
        ImageButton yButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton5);
        yButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) { //play music on click
                if (mp.isPlaying()) {
                    mp.pause();
                } else {
                    mp.start();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed(){ //this is not working
                if(mp.isPlaying())
                {
                    mp.stop(); // stop music on backpress
                }
                //if you want to do the back action aswell, uncomment the following line
                //super.onBackPressed();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the @override is there above the method and you don't declare the method twice.
other alternative is:

```
onKeyDown()
```

or add:

```
super.onBackPressed();
```

in the method onBackPressed (though i dont suggest it really)